# Setting an Android Notification Icon to a remote URL

Tags: android, resources, notifications

I want to use a remote URL (like a favicon) for a notification icon, however the constructor for a notification accepts only a resource ID (which is an integer) instead of something more useful like a `FileInputStream`.

How can I either

- define a new resource for a stream source
- download an icon, add to my resources, and then dynamically get an ID?

Comment: It's the way it is because resources can be optimized while arbitrary streams cannot.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this in Android currently, because resources can only be loaded from the /res/ directory of your APK. See [Resources and Internationalization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html#CreatingResources). The /res/ directory is built when you create your APK and can't be changed after.

Do you expect your Icon to change often enough that you need to query a URL to ensure it is up to date every time you send a notification?

Most applications that need to change their icon would simply put an update out on the Android market.

Comment: Yeah that's not really an option.  I'm doing a client for http://notify.io and a notification can specify it's own icon.  Could I possibly overwrite a raw resource?  (my initial tests say I cannot, I can only read)

Comment: No, you cannot overwrite a raw resource. At present, it is not possible to create Notification icons on the fly.

Comment: That site looks like Growl for the web, pretty neat.

However, it looks like you are stuck with picking a generic Notification icon and using the text to tell the user what application supplied the information.

Answer (score 4):

Since API 11 Android has had the ability to use a Bitmap for a [largeIcon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#largeIcon) in notifications. This has been expanded even further in Jelly Bean to allow entire notifications to be an image, [BigPictureStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html).