# Using custom drawables in an Android Notification

Tags: android, notifications

Is there any way to use an image that I'm generating on the fly as a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic was discussed in a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059933/setting-an-android-notification-icon-to-a-remote-url). Upshot: I don't think it is possible.

**UPDATE**: For tablets or other large-screen devices, on API Level 11+, there is a `largeIcon` property which accepts a `Bitmap`. AFAIK, this is unused on smaller-screen devices, such as phones.

Comment: Oh man, I saw that but decided it wasn't applicable (for some reason).

Answer (score 2):

You can now change the main icon with API 11 (Notification.Builder -> setLargeIcon)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom Notifications view, then you should be able to use a Bitmap object:

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.icon_view, myBitmapObject);
notification.contentView = contentView;
```

For more info see "**Creating a Custom Expanded View**" on this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: This is for the "expanded view", what you see when you open the notification drawer. This is not for the icon (`notification.icon`).

Comment: Ah right, the icon that shows before you open the notifications.  Sorry I wasn't thinking.