# Bitmap as Notification icon

Tags: android

I am android newbie, I have following code:

```
  URL url = new URL(userpic);
  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
  HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
  httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
  httpConn.connect();
  if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();

        // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap
        gdrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        myNotification = new Notification(gdrawable, "Notification!", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

for these code "`Notification(gdrawable, "Notification!",System.currentTimeMillis());`" which will get an error, it need me to get int id.
How can I get gdrawable ID?

Comment: Does anyone find out how to use Bitmap as Notification icon? I really need it. I want to use an external image as notification icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can put image file in res->drawable (or drawable-hdpi,ldpi,mdpi), for example notify.png
and use it
 myNotification = new Notification(R.id.notify,
                                            "Notification!",    System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: Thank Konstantin, but i prefer to load the image on URL with different user. I have find solution, it seems not possible to use url image to for a Notification Icon.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059933/setting-an-android-notification-icon-to-a-remote-url)